# Issue saving message to json file discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to save the most recent message of every user to a JSON file attached to their user ID. Something will be written to the file but it's not the raw message.

```
async def on_message(self, msg):
    if msg.author == self.client.user:
        return
    with open("users.json") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    users[str(msg.author.id)]['response'] = str(msg)
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

I expect the output to be the raw message of what the user sends but instead I get something along the lines of

```
"<Message id=585702897673699338 pinned=False author=<Member id=344030587884929025 name='Siiant' discriminator='5767' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=555525798090768446 name='Bot Test' chunked=True>>>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the string representation of the `Message` object.  To get the content of the message, use [`msg.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)